# I want to scroll the whole screen not only the GridView in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use the GridView in  the half screen but when i use it, it only scroll the gridview portion, i want that when i scroll the whole screen is scroll not only the GridView Portion.

Comment: If I know what you mean, you could add a `ScrollView` as your main layout container for your XML file, but could you be more specific?

Comment: As stated in the comment here, use a ScrollView as the main layout; you should also remember that a ScrollView can only have one child element - in which case you could have a LinearLayout inside it then add other children to the LinearLayout like your GridView etc

Comment: NEVER use a listview/gridview inside a scrollview, it will cause a lot of issues, if you want simply to disable the listview/gridview scroll, check the first answer, in case you want to scroll the listview/gridview and scroll all the layout when you want, i recommend you to use header and footer or use mergeadapter by CommonsWare to merge more grid or lsit together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override Your GridView Touch by this, but remember after this you can not scroll your gridview

```
Yourgridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2" />
 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```